# How do I deal with hacking drones?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

When a hacking drone has latched on to my ship, is there any way of removing it?  What about disabling it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way you can disable them is by damaging the control room on the enemy ship, I believe. I'm not entirely sure but I think the drone that can shoot down incoming projectiles may be able to destroy it before it latches on although this will require good timing. Also an ion shot to the hacking control room will temporarily disable the hacking bot.

Comment: so once its attached there's no way to remove it?

Comment: To my knowledge, no. Just stun the shields and focus the hacking room if you want it gone asap.

Comment: Hacking their hacking room can remove the drone... though they'll likely just launch it again.

Comment: How about the defence drone?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to (temporarily) disable hacking drones without destroying their ship or wrecking their hacking room.

An odd defensive option you have in the event of hacking drones is hacking their hacking room.  When activated, this will prevent (or interrupt) their hacking process.  I personally don't do this very often as I find hacking shields/weapons to be more effective, but in rare circumstances it could be handy, such as when they've hacked an area of your ship that blocks movement to critical sections (bottleneck.)

Comment: However, be cautious.  Hacking their hacking system can potentially blow up their hacking drone...which can then fire again, onto a more damaging part of your system.

Comment: If you're hacking their hacking room, you can probably afford to hack it repeatedly until they run out of drone parts (and keep your systems mostly safe in the process).